# Generate scaladoc for root package

Tags: scala, documentation, package, scaladoc

I'm curious how it's possible to document the *root* package, displayed as the first page in a [scala-doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/) compilation. Can one create a package object referring to the root-package somehow, or is are there any configuration options? The descriptions on the matter are somewhat vague.

Comment: Are there really on one who has insight in this? Darn, scaladoc needs to up their documentation ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be an option for scaladoc called -doc-root-content which was added in 2.9.2.  You can see this in the [ant build.xml for scala 2.9.2](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/build.xml#L1524) and also in the [compiler source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/doc/Settings.scala#L84).  It's not present in 2.9.1, it was added by [this commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/90b0f1b98a5e747bed19b4389bf46ba16fdf734d).

Comment: It's not in the scaladoc specific -help section in 2.9.2 (is in the section for general compile options), which is a bug.  Looks like it's been fixed in master and 2.10.0 release candidates.