# Where does scaladoc look for the rootdoc.txt to create the root doc

Tags: scala, package, scaladoc

This is a duplicate of [Generate scaladoc for root package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059574/generate-scaladoc-for-root-package), however the Answer does not state where `sbt doc` looks for the `rootdoc.txt`.

I added

```
 scalacOptions in doc ++= Seq("-doc-root-content", "rootdoc.txt")
```

to my `build.sbt`, but `sbt doc` does not seem to scan it. I tried to put it next to the `build.sbt`, in `src`, `src/main`, `src/main/scala`

I am using `sbt 0.12.3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your arguments are not given to `scaladoc`at all. I cannot figure out why the command line arguments are not passed when scoping to `doc`, but it works if you do not scope it to `doc`but to `Compile`:

```
 scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-doc-root-content", "rootdoc.txt")
```

With `rootdoc.txt`at the root of your project.

Comment: Doing this causes: `[error] bad option: '-doc-root-content'` when you try `sbt compile`

Answer (score 1):

you should use an abolute file path:

```
scalacOptions in doc <++= baseDirectory map { d =>
  Seq("-doc-root-content", d / "rootdoc.txt" getPath)
}
```

this will make scaladoc look for rootdoc.txt in the root of the project, aka next to build.sbt

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but it does not work. I have a `rootdoc.txt` next to my `build.sbt` and ran `sbt clean doc`. My `target/scala-2.10/api/index.html` just shows an empty package with `package org`

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution seems to be

```
settings(
   // Get scaladoc to add rootdoc.txt content to index.html
   scalacOptions in (Compile,doc) ++= Seq("-doc-root-content", "rootdoc.txt")
).
```

care of https://github.com/pnerg/sbt-scaladoc-settings-plugin/blob/master/README.md

It saddens me this was so hard to figure out.